# How to minimize the length of the GC collections?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I need an application that will run smoothly. I have many serial chunks of computations I need to consecutively perform in short periods of time each, so I don't mind the GC doing it's job and I even can take more frequent collections but what I need to minimize the length of each GC collection.

I would like (if possible) to have 1 milli max pause of thread activity due to the GC each time.

what is the best way to acheive this in .NET (I know that .NET it not the technology for such demands but if it will meet my demands when optimized the save of development hours and flexibility for future specs is good incentive to try it out)?

Comment: Don't use .NET. Its not meant to have that fine control over timing, even other OS functions can interrupt and take longer than that. Are you trying to do some kind of real-time control or something?

Comment: @RonBeyer are you sure about that? I understand for example that there are differences in GC activity between server and desktop versions of windows, even though they both run the same windows kernel... (https://nabacg.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/gc-background-vs-concurrent-mode/)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that. There is no difference between server/desktop versions of windows for GC, but there is by setting the GC to be server/desktop. The difference is the number of threads dedicated to GC and that the server threads can't time out. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx#background_garbage_collection

Comment: Have you tried the low latency modes yet? Are you on 4.5? There have been enormous improvements to the GC over time.

Comment: @usr tx for the suggestion. Sure I can work with 4.5 and I probably even have time to wait for 4.6 with the project's schedule, if it will suggest any imporvment. haven't tried SustainedLowLatency or LowLatency modes yet, do you think that's what they can improve?

Comment: This is *exactly* what they are about.

Answer (score 0):

Right from the MSDN page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx

> The .NET garbage collector provides a high-speed allocation service
>   with good use of memory and no long-term fragmentation problems,
>   however it is possible to do things that will give you much less than
>   optimal performance. To get the best out of the allocator you should
>   consider practices such as the following:
>
> - Allocate all of the memory (or as much as possible) to be used with a given data structure at the same time. Remove temporary allocations
>     that can be avoided with little penalty in complexity.
> - Minimize the number of times object pointers get written, especially those writes made to older objects.
> - Reduce the density of pointers in your data structures.
> - Make limited use of finalizers, and then only on "leaf" objects, as much as possible. Break objects if necessary to help with this.
> - A regular practice of reviewing your key data structures and conducting memory usage profiles with tools like Allocation Profiler
>     will go a long way to keeping your memory usage effective and having
>     the garbage collector working its best for you.

As Ron mentioned in his comment. You have to be extra smart with .NET if you want a lot of control over the GC.

Comment: When you run the GC, it will run until it's done. The only way to get better performance out of the GC is to write code that maximizes efficiency with how the GC works underneath. You can manually run a Collect() operation yourself and specify the number of objects to collect. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc(v=vs.110).aspx